# How have one child action & call it from multiple controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, child-actions

I have one Child action that call it from it's own controller & return Views/Shared/PartialViewName belong to my child action. again repeat this in another controller and it do the same. every thing is ok. but i reapet child action in some controllers [DRY](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself&ei=ceM_U-qzHMK0ygHg6YGwBA&usg=AFQjCNHbd1Tlapfbw-ez3fqqI1cnJXhKkA&bvm=bv.64125504,d.aWc)

How share one child action among controllers is it possible like shared partial views in views folder?

I utulize below but doesn't work:

```
@Html.Action("actionName","ControllerName")
```

**update:** 
I don't use Areas

here's my code:

```
public class ItemCatController : Controller
    {
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult PopulateTree() { return View("Tree", GetTree());  ... lots of other code }
     }
```

return view:

```
<h2>ItemCat Index</h2>
<hr />

<button onclick="New()">new</button>
<br />
@Html.Action("PopulateTree")
```

and this:

```
public class ItemController : Controller
    {
        *// repeat these codes again, this is aginst DRY principle.*
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult PopulateTree() { return View("Tree", GetTree());  ... lots of other code }
     }
```

return this :

```
<h2>Index Item</h2>
<hr />

@Html.Action("PopulateTree")
<br />
```

Comment: show both the controller code.

Comment: @AmarDuplantier Is there any ambiguous?